# Retrieve the changed url after request

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I need to retrieve the changed URL after making a request in Python.

For example, I have an URL https://www.instantstreetview.com/s/59.421688492195614,24.793857100774545 that changes to https://www.instantstreetview.com/@59.42103,24.794265,-17.51h,5p,0.91z. I need to retrieve the changed url. I tried the requests module, but it shows that the URL was not changed.

```py
    import requests
    
    response = requests.get('https://www.instantstreetview.com/s/59.421688492195614,24.793857100774545')
    if response.history:
        print("Request was redirected")
        for resp in response.history:
            print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
        print("Final destination:")
        print(response.status_code, response.url)
    else:
        print("Request was not redirected")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at this request in Chrome Dev Tools and see that it does not redirect, one can see that this request returns a response status code of 200. If there was a redirect one would expect to see a 3XX status code, normally 302.
[image: See here]

Comment: But I can see that it transforms the URL. Is there any way I can retrieve the transformed URL?